# Show activity indicator on custom cell button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have custom cell with button. When tap on button I download video from server. During download I need to show activity indicator, but it does not show `activityindicatorview`.

Code:

```
 RBFriendChatTableViewCell *Cell = [ tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Identifier];
 [Cell.m_btnDownLoad addTarget:self action:@selector(downLoadImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(void)downLoadImage:(UIbutton *)sender{
indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
     indicator.center = CGPointMake(5, 5);
     [sender addSubview:indicator];
     [indicator startAnimating]
     NSString *strUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",chatImage,[dicChatList objectForKey:@"file"]];
                NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:strUrl];
                NSData *movieData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
                NSURL *fileURL = [self grabFileURL:[dicChatList objectForKey:@"file"]];
                [movieData writeToURL:fileURL atomically:YES];
                [m_arrDownloadVideoName addObject:[dicChatList objectForKey:@"file"]];
}
```

Comment: So, what's your problem? Have you tried adding [UIActivityIndicatorView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/) to your cell and hide/unhide at the right time?

Comment: yes i did.but it is not showing on button

Comment: i don not want to add it on cell. i want to show it on button

Comment: Have you tried to bring it to the front?

`[sender bringSubviewToFront: indicator];`

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the UI in main thread, you are downloading the video in the same thread, it should be done in a background Asynch thread, for your current situation following fix might help but its best to do the downloading in background and update the UI once its done.

```
-(void)downLoadImage:(UIbutton *)sender{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle : UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
        indicator.center = CGPointMake(5, 5);
        [sender addSubview:indicator];
        [indicator startAnimating];
              });
    NSString *strUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",chatImage,[dicChatList objectForKey:@"file"]];
    NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:strUrl];
    NSData *movieData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSURL *fileURL = [self grabFileURL:[dicChatList objectForKey:@"file"]];
    [movieData writeToURL:fileURL atomically:YES];
    [m_arrDownloadVideoName addObject:[dicChatList objectForKey:@"file"]];
}
```

Comment: stop animation should be inside async block?

Comment: if you are loading the data in an ASync block you need a callback to do the stop animating, if you are just using main thread for UI update (the way I have written) then Stop animation can work outside the block as well since you would call it once the thread has already completed and downloaded your video (so CPU cycles are free)